# Understanding XGBoost model dump output of a very simple tree

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, classification, xgboost

I am trying to understand the model dump output from XGBoost. I would like to step through and see exactly how the model arrived at it's prediction. To simplify I trained a model with 1 tree and 1 max depth, and as expected all records get one of two predictions as it has a single split - the values are {0.5386398434638977, 0.5011891722679138}.  However, when I look at the model dump I see the following

```
booster[0]:
0:[f40<70.5] yes=1,no=2,missing=1
    1:leaf=0.00475667231
    2:leaf=0.154868156
```

I have no idea how to interpret this in a way that makes sense with the prediction. What am I missing?

Comment: i would suggest you to move your question to "Data Science Community" (https://datascience.stackexchange.com) so it get's more visible for the relevant group of people.

Comment: Thanks. Answered here from datascience.stackexchange https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60208/understanding-python-xgboost-model-dump-output-of-a-very-simple-tree/60210#60210